# How to get data to show as a barplot?

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

Here is my data. I am trying to use R to represent the data as a barplot.

```
row.names,we,dna,dftd,ee,ebola,onc,smt
Author,4.75,7.7222,4.0698,6.9796,6.9545,8.3809,4.6391
Journal,0.45,0.4444,0.7442,0.6327,0.5151,0.5,0.5325
Year,0.35,0.5278,0.5349,0.3469,0.5,0.1548,0.1243
```

`we,dna,dftd,ee,ebola,onc,smt` are all article names. `4.75:4.6391` is Author variance in each article. `.45:.5325` is Journal variance in each article. `.35:.1243` is Year variance in each article.

The end goal is to create a bar plot with variance on the y-axis and the article titles on the x-axis. Each article title should have 3 bars above it for Author, Journal, and Year.

I can't figure out how to get this data to show as a barplot in R.

I loaded it with:

```
bp=read.csv(file.choose(),header=T)
```

If from here I type
`barplot(bp)` it tells me the height must be a vector or matrix, all I know about vectors is that you can create them with `c(...)`.

I have searched everywhere and tried for a few days before asking here.

I know it's a simple command but I just cant figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to feed `barplot()` heights in a vector or matrix, as you note from your error message.

I am assuming that you have your data in a `data.frame()` right now.

```
dat <- read.csv(text = "row.names,we,dna,dftd,ee,ebola,onc,smt
Author,4.75,7.7222,4.0698,6.9796,6.9545,8.3809,4.6391
Journal,0.45,0.4444,0.7442,0.6327,0.5151,0.5,0.5325
Year,0.35,0.5278,0.5349,0.3469,0.5,0.1548,0.1243")

# make data.frame into a matrix of numbers and get rid of the row.names
dat_matrix <- data.matrix(dat[, -1])

# make a barplot of the variances for each article
barplot(dat_matrix, beside = TRUE)
```

The above creates this plot:
[image]

If you want, you can also accomplish this with the ggplot2 package.
You would need to reshape your data from wide to long before plotting, which can be done with reshape2.

```
# reshape data from wide to long and rename variables
library(reshape2)
dat_long <- melt(dat, id.vars = "row.names",
              variable.name = "article_name",
              value.name = "variance_value")

library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(data = dat_long, aes(x = article_name, y = variance_value, fill = row.names)) 
p <- p + geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
p
```

The ggplot2 version:

[image]